# Is it possible to send an ACH payment directly from a US bank account to a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to send a payment through PayPal, where the payment originates as an ACH payment, and then is sent to a PayPal account holder, without having to originate the payment from a PayPal account?

Put differently — we would like to send a payment to a PayPal account holder, without first having to pull the money into our own PayPal account. We process payments via ACH, and we'd prefer to not have to deposit the funds into our PayPal account before transferring them to the destination PayPal account. We'd prefer to be able to deposit them directly into the PayPal account.

Is that possible?

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this at http://superuser.com/?  (Even though it might be borderline even there.)  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: It could be possible if the bank allows it. However I do not know of any bank that provides this sort of API.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that would be to have a 3rd party user add your bank account to their PayPal account so they could submit deposits directly into their PayPal account from your bank.  I'm guessing that's not what you're after.

If you simply submit a regular PayPal payment, though, while it will technically flow through the PayPal account it would go directly to the receiver's PayPal account instantly as long as you have a credit card associated with your PayPal account.  This is much faster than ACH and protects your bank account details from receivers as well, so that's really what I would recommend anyway.

The only disadvantage I can see to having it flow through PayPal is may an additional entry for your accountant to deal with in the books (transfer from bank to PayPal, then payment from PayPal to vendor) but that is not a very big problem.  The advantages far outweigh that in my opinion.